# xrandr --pos doesn't do anything

Tags: xrandr

I hooked up a tv to my linux computer.  I noticed the screen was offset by about 200px to the right, leaving behind a black vertical strip on the left of the screen and cutting off a portion of the right of hte screen.

So I executed the command `sudo xrandr --output VGA1 --pos -200x0` but all that did was blink the tv for a split second without changing anything.

I tried repeating the xrandr with the --pos option on another computer.  I noticed that the screen reposition as expected for just a fraction of a second before returning to it's original position.

How do I get xrandr to re-position screens ? What's wrong with my commands?

Comment: Are you sure you can give it negative positions? Did you try a positive number? Also see this: http://superuser.com/questions/300381/use-xrandr-to-set-the-absolute-position-of-the-screen

Comment: This might shed light on things too: http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=352151

Comment: What about if you give it --pos 0x0?

Comment: thanks yeah i looked at those posts earlier and they didn't help.  When i use negative position on one of my monitors, it does re-position to the left as expected, but then it snaps back to the original position in less than a second

Comment: The bit about having to re-position within the virtual space might be related to your issue.

Comment: I know this is old, but on Ubuntu 14.04.4 I'm getting nowhere with xrandr either, with various commands (transform etc) screen flashes but the result is not what you expect. I have a suspicion that whilst it is supposed to change parameters on the fly, possibly lightdm (in my case), already set up and running, isn't paying attention, therefore whatever xrandr has done is only partially applied. Unfortunately trying to restart lightdm produces a locked up system.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and found this thread: [How do I align the bottom edges of two monitors with xrandr?](https://superuser.com/questions/485120/how-do-i-align-the-bottom-edges-of-two-monitors-with-xrandr). BatchyX's answer helped me a lot.