# How can I make xrandr modifications persist for more than 1 second?

Tags: xrandr, multi-monitor, brightness

**Updates**:

- This question describes similar symptoms [Ubuntu - Xrandr doesn't change my resolution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247874/ubuntu-xrandr-doesnt-change-my-resolution), but it seems like the underlying cause is different as there are no changes to my Xorg-log files in the last 6 months.
- Another similar question without answer [xrandr --pos doesn't do anything](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108019/xrandr-pos-doesnt-do-anything)

---

My external screen is too bright, even on the lowest brightness setting. Too dampen the brightness, I am trying to use `xrandr --output HDMI2 --brightness 0.5` as detailed in this post [How do dim screen, even if artifically, below the minimum?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181496/how-do-dim-screen-even-if-artifically-below-the-minimum).

However, while this command does lower the brightness, the screen switches back to the brighter level in an instant. Basically, the screen blinks once in a darker brightness. I tried with my primary laptop screen, `xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness 0.5`, with the same outcome. I also tried changing the gamma, `xrandr --output eDP1 --gamma 1.0:1.0:0.5`, again with the same transient result, this time a one second flash in a yellow tint.

How can I make `xrandr` modifications persist until I specifically change it? If it persists through reboot or not isn't a big deal.

My `xrandr` is version 1.5.0 and I am on Antergos Linux (an Arch derivative) with Gnome 3.20.2 and kernel 4.6.2-1.

Comment: It might be your desktop environment imposing its own configuration. What desktop environment are you using? Do you have the same problem with a different account using a different desktop environment?

Comment: I am using Gnome 3.20.2, updated the question. I don't have any other desktop manager installed, but I tried in a Gnome Wayland session. In Wayland, the same `xrandr` command produces no visible output, not even a flicker of the screen as previously.

Comment: ´xrandr´ shouldnt affect a Wayland desktop because its not an x server. Well, it might if the Wayland session is run atop an x server, which i guess might explain the flash you mentioned in a comment on the other question.

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks for explaining why `xrandr` is not affecting the Wayland desktop session. The flash I am seeing is only happening in the Gnome and Gnome Classic session, which I guess both run the xserver. I still don't understand what is causing the flash and preventing the `xrandr` changes from persisting.

Answer (score 1):

What you want, is to set the backlight to your desired value. Since you are on Gnome 3, you might want to change it in Gnome.

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power --method org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen Brightness "50"
```

If that does not work, the ArchWiki has many alternatives, including ACPI and kernel parameters ...

Select your monitors in the following:

```
# ls /sys/class/backlight/
```

inspect the maximum brightness:

```
# cat /sys/class/backlight/<device>/max_brightness
```

Then you set it to your desired value:

```
# echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Source (ArchWiki):
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight

DISCLAIMER: I do not run Gnome 3, so cannot test this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have since stopped using an external screen, so this haven't been an issue for me lately. I have also moved to i3, so I am not able to validate whether this works with the setup I originally described in my question, sorry about that.